# Camera Image is too small

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, arrays, android-camera-intent

From the last few days, I am suffering from the problem of Camera Image which is too small with the size of **120 x 160**.

The Scenario is when I capture the image from camera and convert that image to byte[], it becomes too small.

Below is the code which I am using:

```
 Bitmap unscaledBitmap  = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 unscaledBitmap  .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, bytes);
 byte[] bytesDoc1 = bytes.toByteArray();
```

Don't have any idea about it but I have tried many solutions given on SO but all not worked for me.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify a path for the camera intent to store the real image. Because the `data.getExtras().get("data");` just get a thumbnail from the real image.

In the official docs you can find how to do it: https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#java

I have extracted from there the part of the code that you need to use.

This is how you should create the Intent to take the picture:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

// Create the File where the photo should go
File photoFile = createImageFile();

        
if (photoFile != null) {
   takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
   startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
}
```

And this is the method to create the File with the image in order to be able to read it:

```
private File createImageFile() {
        
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String imageFileName = "NAME_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        
        return image;
    }
```

Then you can read the real path of the created picture.

For more information, please refer to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#java).

Answer (score 0):

What you get is only the thumbnail.

If you want the real image its best to give the camera a file path where to store the image. You can use then that path in onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I have already tried it but it also not worked for ME.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is too late to help you out on this issue. I faced this issue as well and just figured out why that photo is so small.
The reason was because on some phones (LG Tribute 5), the default picture size is somehow using the lowest one (160x120). In order to fix this bug, you have to get the supported picture sizes list from the camera.
Something like `camera.getParameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()`, and try to pick the minimum resolution you want, then `setPictureSize` to the best matched size you have picked.
That would fix the issue for sure.

Answer (score -2):

I used scaleType `fitXY` and it worked

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPicture"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    scaleType="fitXY"/>
```